# How to go back to the previous page using JSF

Tags: jsf

I would like to implement a hyperlink leading to the respective previous page which should appear supplied with the same data used for its previous display (similar to the effect of the "history-back" button).

Are there any best practices to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the features of Seam where they have tried to improve on standard JSF. Here's the relevant part of the [reference](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/2.1.2.CR2/reference/en-US/html/jbpm.html#d0e6713).